# Why select is not working in eloquent in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: eloquent, eager-loading, laravel-5.7

The following code is working fine:

```
Post::with(['user'])
    ->get();
```

but when I try to filter it using select, it returns null in user relations.

```
Post::with(['user' => function($query){
    $query->select('name');
}])
->select('id', 'slug', 'title', 'body', 'created_at')
->get();
```

relation inside User Model:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

relation inside Post Model:

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select the foreign key (`posts.user_id`) and the owner key (`users.id`):

```php
Post::with(['user' => function($query){
    $query->select('id', 'name');
}])
->select('id', 'slug', 'title', 'body', 'created_at', 'user_id')
->get();
```

You can also use this shorter version:

```php
Post::with('user:id,name')
    ->select('id', 'slug', 'title', 'body', 'created_at', 'user_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: can you explain why?

Comment: Eager loading can't work without them. If you fetch the post without the `user_id` column, there's no way to get the related user. The same goes for the user's `id` column.

Answer (score 0):

can you please do with

```
DB::table('users')->where('votes', '>', 100)->sharedLock()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the foreign_key to the select statement.